# disable transparent hugepages

Tags: linux, kernel, sysctl

We are installing SAP HANA in a **RAID** machine. As part of the installation step, it is mentioned that,

```
 To disable the usage of transparent hugepages set the kernel settings 
 at runtime with echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

So instead of runtime, if I wanted to make this a permanent change, should I add the above line inside `/proc/vmstat` file?

Comment: Note that if you're using some of the solutions mentioned here, on a system that also runs 'tuned', tuned may override those solutions.  See here for more info: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1189868

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To make options such as this permanent you'll typically add them to the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`. You can see a full list of the options available using this command:

```
$ sysctl -a
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | head -5
kernel.sched_child_runs_first = 0
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 6000000
kernel.sched_latency_ns = 18000000
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 3000000
kernel.sched_shares_ratelimit = 750000
```

You can look for `hugepage` in the output like so:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | grep hugepage
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_hugepages_mempolicy = 0
vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
```

#### It's not there?

However looking through the output I did not see `transparent_hugepage`. Googling a bit more I did come across this Oracle page which discusses this very topic. The page is titled: [Configuring HugePages for Oracle on Linux (x86-64)](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/configuring-huge-pages-for-oracle-on-linux-64.php).

Specifically on that page they mention how to [disable the hugepage feature](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/configuring-huge-pages-for-oracle-on-linux-64.php#disabling-transparent-hugepages).

*excerpt*

> The preferred method to disable Transparent HugePages is to add "transparent_hugepage=never" to the kernel boot line in the "/etc/grub.conf" file.
>
> ```
>    title Oracle Linux Server (2.6.39-400.24.1.el6uek.x86_64)
>             root (hd0,0)
>             kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.39-400.24.1.el6uek.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_ol6112-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=uk
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16  rd_NO_DM rd_LVM_LV=vg_ol6112/lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_ol6112/lv_root rhgb quiet numa=off
>     transparent_hugepage=never
>             initrd /initramfs-2.6.39-400.24.1.el6uek.x86_64.img
> ```
>
> The server must be rebooted for this to take effect.

Alternatively you can add the command to your `/etc/rc.local` file.

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

I think I would go with the 2nd option, since the first will be at risk of getting unset when you upgrade from one kernel to the next.

You can confirm that it worked with the following command after rebooting:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
```

Comment: You can make the first option survive kernel updates by adding transparent_hugepage=never to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT option in /etc/default/grub on most distributions.

Comment: If the output of ``cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`` is ``[always] madvise never``, then the status is ``always`` or that it is enabled (note the ``[]`` brackets around ``always``)

Comment: Don't confuse hugepages and transparent hugepages. The latter can cause many issues, mainly high CPU usage while constantly trying to defragment memory and convert normal 4kB pages into huge 2MB pages.

Comment: @Rwky doesn't seem to work on EC2 instances, for some reason.

Comment: @Rwky -- when tweaking as per your suggestion - I'd emphasize the next action after saving the file is to execute `sudo update-grub` to get the new settings "written in stone".  +1 for pointing the grub file line.

Comment: VERY important to heed @Marki555 warning.

Comment: An update for those on EC2, cloudimg adds the file /etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg which overrides the settings in /etc/default/grub adding a file /etc/default/grub.d/99-transparent-hugepage.cfg with the content GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT transparent_hugepage=never" will solve this.

Comment: After adding a file /etc/default/grub.d/99-transparent-hugepage.cfg with the content GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT transparent_hugepage=never" as @Rwky mentioned, run grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg to generate the updated grub.cfg. After a restart, cat /proc/cmdline will contain transparent_hugepage=never

Answer (score 14):

I just wanted to add to this question as I was trying to disable transparent hugepages on CentOS v6 in order to enable TokuDB for MariaDB. I added the script mentioned by @slm to `/etc/rc.local` and it disabled transparent hugepages. However, because of the way startup scripts work in Linux, `/etc/rc.local` is executed after all the services are started. Therefore, transparent huge pages was being disabled after MariaDB was already started and the TokuDB engine wouldn't initialize. The only other way to disable transparent hugepages is by adding `transparent_hugepage=never` to the kernel parameter.

I noticed @Rwky's comment `You can make the first option survive kernel updates by adding transparent_hugepage=never to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT option in /etc/default/grub on most distributions.` and found out that CentOS doesn't support the `/etc/default/grub` file and was worried about `transparent_hugepage=never` disappearing from the kernel parameters when it is updated. But not to worry, CentOS is setup to keep any changes made to the kernel parameters in grub so when it is updated they are kept.

To also add, the proper way to modify the kernel parameters for grub is with `grubby`. I created this simple script to add `transparent_hugepage=never` to each kernel with `grubby`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

for KERNEL in /boot/vmlinuz-*; do
    grubby --update-kernel="$KERNEL" --args='transparent_hugepage=never'
done
```

Comment: For an option such as this I would still probably try and add it to /`etc/sysctl.conf` since that will be consistently applied to any Kernel that may ever be installed on the box.

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you modify the <code>/etc/default/grub</code> file, you need to run `grub-mkconfig` as 'root' to generate the actual configuration file for grub.

Comment: For an EC2 ubuntu instance, I have to modify the `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg` file instead of the `/etc/default/grub` to make it work.

Comment: I am using CentOS 6.6. I have modified `/etc/rc.local` but it is not working for me. Can you please explain the root case to me.

Comment: @s.singh As I stated ``/etc/rc.local is executed after all the services are started`` so it needs to be disabled at the kernel level

Comment: I tried adding `transparent_hugepage=never` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and restarted the machine but still it is not working. Do I need to run your script ?

Comment: StackExchange comments aren't for support. If your having problems, I suggest you ask a question on of the Stack Exchange websites.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an implementation using puppet:

```
exec { "disable_transparent_hugepage_enabled":
  command => "/bin/echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled",
  unless  => "/bin/grep -c '\[never\]' /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled 2>/dev/null",
}

exec { "disable_transparent_hugepage_defrag":
  command => "/bin/echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag",
  unless  => "/bin/grep -c '\[never\]' /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag 2>/dev/null",
}
```

Answer (score 7):

All of the above didn't work for me on an EC2 Ubuntu 16.04, but this did:

```
sudo apt install hugepages
sudo hugeadm --thp-never
```

Comment: This didn't persist the change

Comment: are you conflating `huge pages` with `transparent huge pages`?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to [github](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PyYoshi/a7ca64b6c92b5ef1834b/raw/d49c0a4333f25fb6c58c60536ebba809e24d0076/disable-transparent-huge-pages.service) & [PyYoshi](https://gist.github.com/PyYoshi)
I found this example for systemd

Create the file

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/disable-transparent-huge-pages.service
```

Put this into the service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable Transparent Huge Pages

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/echo "never" | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/echo "never" | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For debian/ubuntu users

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable Transparent Huge Pages

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/echo "never" | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/echo "never" | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable the service

```
systemctl enable disable-transparent-huge-pages
systemctl start disable-transparent-huge-pages
systemctl status disable-transparent-huge-pages
```

Comment: On Debian Buster, the path to *echo* is `/bin/echo`.

Answer (score 4):

Since the kernel line `transparent_hugepage=never` only disables half of what I need (both, for annoying mongodb failing/logs), that I didn't persist through `systemd` startup script but now have: `echo never | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`. That works in either systemctl boot script (when properly configured one in `/etc/systemd/system`) or straight from the cli as is.

Comment: Could you please expand your instructions to also include the "properly configured script" and steps how to setup everything? Official MongoDB instructions https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/ show the old way, while now that systemd is more common, it would be nice to have this in an systemd way.

Answer (score 4):

In case of Redis, it also emits a warning which suggests to disable THP. But as noted in [the bug report](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3176), on many distros `/etc/rc.local` is executed after services and it has no effect on them until they restart. Also note that in virtualised environments (e.g. Digitalocean) you can't control GRUB settings.

The solution in such case is use dedicated *init* script to disable *transparent huge pages* as [this page](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/thp-disable.html) suggests, by settings `X-Start-Before`. For example, Debian *init* script for Redis:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          disable-thp
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:
# X-Start-Before:    redis-server
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Disable THP
# Description:       disables Transparent Huge Pages (THP) on boot
### END INIT INFO

case $1 in
start)
  if [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage ]; then
    echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
    echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
  else
    return 0
  fi
;;
esac
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for saving me the time :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick hack for Ansible (I don't want to go managing a template for `/etc/rc.local`):

```
- name: Disable Transparent Huge Pages at boot
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/rc.local
    line: "if [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage ]; then echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled ; echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag ; fi"
  register: transparent_hugepage
- name: Disable disabled rc.local
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/rc.local
    line: 'exit 0'
    state: absent
- name: Disable Transparent Huge Pages at run time 1/2
  command: echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
  when: transparent_hugepage|changed
- name: Disable Transparent Huge Pages at run time 2/2
  command: echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
  when: transparent_hugepage|changed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meet with the problem

```
-bash: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag: Permission denied
```

even with sudo, try the commands below:

```
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled'
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on the Unix SE! Note, it would be much better if you would also explain, what your commands are doing.

Answer (score 0):

In SLES11 SP3 with YAST and GRUB bootloader we have to add `transparent_hugepage=never` in [ YAST-bootloader-edit- line with optional kernel parameter ]. **NOTE:** This tool changes the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

Only after making this change and rebooting resulted in in disabling THP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another puppet solution in the Forge:
https://forge.puppetlabs.com/ramseymcgrath/remove_hugepage/

Just use:

```
include remove_hugepage
```

in your puppet node definition.