# How to Disable Transparent Huge Pages in CentOS6.6

Tags: linux, centos, hadoop

I am trying to `disable` **Transparent Huge Pages** in my `CentOS` for `HDP2.2` installation. I am using [this link](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.6.0.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ch01s04s08.html) for the reference but I am still getting the issue.

I tried to add this also:

Adding the following lines to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` and restarted the machine.

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

And give execution rights to the file:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Reference from Hortonworks link  and [disable transparent hugepages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages)

I have tried editing `/etc/rc.local` and restated the machine.

```
if 
  test -f /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/defrag; then 
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/defrag 
fi

if 
  test -f /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled; then 
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled 
fi
```

When I do: `cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` I get below message on console:

```
[always] madvise never
```

Can you please explain the exact meaning of this message.

I rebooted the machine and restarted the Ambari but ambari installation wizard is still saying that`Transparent Huge Pages` is still enabled . I am new in it and looking for some help to resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried the way they suggested there but no luck for me :(

Comment: What didn't work for you? Details, please!

Comment: I tried the steps which I have mentioned in my question. The same steps are mentioned in the duplicate post also. I don't want to edit  `/etc/grub.conf` file for this. If editing `/etc/rc.local` file works then why it is not working for me in CentOS6.6

Answer (score 1):

You can add `transparent_hugepage=never` as a kernel parameter.

Edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and add it to the kernel line.

Example:

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/vda1 rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty0 crashkernel=auto SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet transparent_hugepage=never
```

Then reboot.