# Is it possible to disable Transparent Huge pages on the fly?

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, huge-pages

In order to disable the `THP`

We did the following on all 635 `RHEL` machines (we have `rhel 7.5` version)

This lines are from bash script that we runs on all machines

**Step 1**

```
[[ -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled ]] && echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[[ -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag  ]] && echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

*Verification:*

```
cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]

cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always madvise [never]
```

But as all know this steps are not considered when machine `restarted/rebooted`

**Step 2**

So we also did this , we append the following lines to `/etc/rc.local`

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

**The question is:**

Does `step 1` as I mentioned above really `disabled` the `THP` on the fly?

Note - also other info from one typical machine

```
sysctl -a | grep hugepage
vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_hugepages_mempolicy = 0
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
```

reference - [Configuring Transparent Huge Pages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-configuring_transparent_huge_pages).

Comment: not see how we can do it from sysctl.conf

Comment: Sorry, yes, `/sys` isn’t `/proc/sys`!

Comment: yes: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-configuring_transparent_huge_pages

Comment: in RHEL/CentOS 7.x I strongly recommend `yum install tuned*` and `yum install tuna`

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-performance_monitoring_tools-tuned_and_tuned_adm

Comment: we have hadoop machines and tuned not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does step 1 as I mentioned above really disabled the THP on the fly?

**Yes**, any thing you do in `sysfs` is done on the fly. It's already documented in the kernel doc/[transhuge.html](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html)

**However**, Quoting from https://access.redhat.com/solutions/46111

> **NOTE:** Running the above commands will stop only creation and usage of
>   the new THP. The THP which were created and used at the moment the
>   above commands were run would not be disassembled into the regular
>   memory pages. To get rid of THP completely the system should be
>   rebooted with THP disabled at boot time.

There is a [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages) with your same question. There, [ub3rst4r](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/40788/ub3rst4r) explained that `/etc/rc.local` didn't work for his use case since it is executed after all the services are started

So, I highly recommend following the official way mentioned in the same kernel doc/[transhuge.html](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html)

> You can change the sysfs boot time defaults of Transparent Hugepage
>   Support by passing the parameter ... transparent_hugepage=never to the
>   kernel command line.

You can of course make it persistent using `/etc/default/grub`. Also, I recommend testing after the reboot with

```bsh
grep AnonHugePages /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
```

You should get a value of 0 if it's disabled properly.

Comment: so all my procedure is right>

Comment: @yael I updated the answer to reflect a better way of doing it and verifying based on offical docs and others experiences.

Comment: /etc/default/grub is too risky , better /etc/rc.local

Comment: @yael: As I said try rc.local and if you got 0 value in your case, that's good. However, with `rc.local` some pages might be reserved by other services that run before `rc.local`. `/etc/default/grub` is not an alternative to `rc.local`. It guarantee that the pages are disabled before any other service manage to use it. Of course, you should always take a backup and make sure you know how to fix things in case something goes wrong or else don't do it. Can you paste the output of `grep AnonHugePages /proc/meminfo` after reboot

Comment: grep AnonHugePages /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:  11001856 kB

Comment: sorry but I dont want to edit the grub with script , its can be risky when edit not do the things right in file , so I not have choice

Comment: @yael: Then don't do it. Sometimes, with some hosting services, you don't even have the option to edit the boot loader. so `rc.local` is a good way to keep in your arsenal but to make the answer useful I clarified the difference, any thing remaining now that I didn't answer for you?